# Passing in Params to JS.ERB file from controller? [Rails 3]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameters

I am trying to allow users to "import" saved Missions into a Syllabus post. A Syllabus has many Missions, and the Syllabus form is a nested form where the user can 'Add Missions,' which will append a new Missions textbox.

When I "import" missions, I want the javascript to
 1. click "add missions" link (which adds a nested form) 
 2. input values of the "imported missions" into the ckeditor textbox.

_IMPORT_FORM.HTML.ERB

```
 <%= form_tag(import_missions_path, :method => :post, :id => "import-js" )  do |f| %>
  <ul>
  <% current_user.folders.find_by_order(1).missions.each do |mission| %>
<li> <%= check_box_tag "mission_ids[]", mission.id %>
  <%= mission.id.to_s + ". " + mission.title %> </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag "Import ", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

this then goes to SYLLABUSES#IMPORT

```
def import
@missions_hash = []
    #loop through each mission id from :missions_id
params[:mission_ids].each do |id|
 @missions_hash << Mission.find(id)
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to edit_syllabus_path(@syllabus), notice: "imported" }
  format.js { render 'folders/import.js' }
end
end
```

which I then want to render IMPORT.JS.ERB file, and pass in  the @missions_hash. The code below is probably wrong, and this is where I need help fixing it.

IMPORT.JS.ERB

```
//loop for each mission passed in 
<% @mission_hash.each do |mission| %>
  //click add missions
  $('#add-missions-button').trigger('click');
  //pass in mission.title & mission.content to form textbox value
<% end %>
```

What is the correct syntax to pass in the Ruby params into this Javascript.erb file? Also, I want to copy the 'title' and 'content' of the imported Missions into the newly added mission form box:

```
  <%= f.text_field :title, :class =>'row span6' %>
  <%= f.cktext_area :content, :toolbar => 'MyToolbar', :class => 'row span6', :rows => '5', :placeholder => "What is the first step a learner should do? (e.g. Watch an intro video, read certain article)" %>
```

How would I copy it into the values of these  textboxes, so the user can edit it after importing?

I realize this question is badly organized, but I tried to make it as simple as possible without explaining the entire background. I'm still a beginner so please understand..

Comment: Basically you're trying to make the view `import.js.erb` render the same contents as the view `_import_form.html.erb`?

Comment: No,so think of it this way. one DAY has many TASKS, but there are times you need to do the same TASK on a different day. So instead of typing that task every single time, you save that task, and you "import" it to your new day. But I don't just want to simply make that task a child of the new day,because I want to leave open the option for the creator to edit that task in the textbox. So basically I just want to copy the contents of the task and put it in to the textbox with javascript/ajax.

Answer (score 1):

OK,  IMPORT.JS.ERB  is javascript that will be sent back to your browser,  but because of the .ERB extension,  it will be processed by embedded ruby first,  in the context of the controller,  before being sent to the browser,  so you can use standard ERB syntax ,

```
 <%= @something %>
```

anywhere in your javascript to manipulate the javascript being sent back,  so you could do this:

import.js.erb:

```
$('#somediv').html('<%= escape_javascript(@missions_hash.inspect) %>');
```

If you have a div on your page with id = 'someday',  it's contents should be set to a dump of missions_hash.   This also assumes your are using AJAX, i.e.:

```
<%= form_tag(import_missions_path, 
  :method => :post, 
  :id => "import-js" , 
  :remote=>true)  do |f| %>
```

BUT,  you need to TELL rails to pre-process the javascript file with embedded ruby,  so you'd have to change:

```
render 'folders/import.js'
```

to

```
render 'folders/import.js.erb'
```

There are cleaner ways to accomplish what you want overall,  but I think you for now you just have to figure our the embedded ruby and javascript combination.

Comment: I did everything you suggested, but I'm not sure if it still processes Ruby code inside the import.js.erb file. Here's the gist https://gist.github.com/2879813 of my code. In the import.js.erb file, I want to loop through the MISSIONS_HASH and create a new textbox for each hash, and fill the textbox with some attributes of the MISSION being looped from the MISSIONS_HASH

Comment: So,  when you check one of the checkboxes in the _import_form,  you want to update something in _mission_fields.  Question,  are both those partials rendered on the same page?

Comment: Yes. So I have a _form, and within that, I have multiple nested _missions_fields (which is appended when I click 'Add Mission' button), and I have the _import_form rendered as a modal when I click on a button inside the _form.

Comment: Essentially, I want to click the button to [1] show _import_form as a modal popup, [2] submit it, [3] Add extra _mission_fields inside the _form, [4] fill in each of the _missions_fields with the attributes of the checkboxed missions passed in from the _import_form

Answer (score 0):

i think you shouldn't do that, because you will meet problem when sprocket compile. It will compile in the first time when file change. if you want to pass variable to js you can try that gem [client variable](https://github.com/coffa/client_variable)